# Catch nondeterminism by error'ing on iterating pointer-keyed maps

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

It's been a few times we've found nondeterministic issues in the codebase I'm working on, and so far it's almost been root caused to the use of `std::[unordered_]map/set<T*,U>`, where the key is a pointer, combined with iteration on the map, usually in the form of a range-based for loop (since pointer values may change between executions, iteration order is nondeterministic).

I was wondering if there was some black template magic one could use to inject a `static_assert` when `begin()` is called on such a container. I think `begin()` is the best place to do this, or maybe `iterator::operator++`, since constructing iterators otherwise, such as a result of `find()`, is okay.

I thought I could overload `std::begin`, but the rules for range-based for loops state that `.begin()` is used if it exists. So, I'm out of ideas. Is there a clever trick to do this?

**Further clarification**: No custom comparator is involved, the direct value of the pointer (aka the address of the target object) is the key. This is fine for insertion and lookup, and only becomes a problem when iterating over the container since the order is based on unpredictable pointer values. I'm trying to find existing cases like this in a large existing codebase.

Comment: Don't store pointers in the container?  Use a custom comparison/hash that dereferences the pointer, so the ordering is based on what is pointed at and not the pointer value?

Comment: You could write a `clang_tidy` checker (https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/) looking for range-based for loops that iterate over an `unordered_map` (or `set`) with a particular set of template arguments. That's not a `static_assert`, so it won't find a newly-added case, but it could help.

Comment: Remember that the keys of the map/set must be const. If you use a pointer as key, you must not alter the ordering (e.g update the pointed data used to compare key)

Comment: @Nico238 Why can't they update the pointed to data?  The pointer is const, not what it points to.  The default comparator only compares address so it doesn't care about the state of the pointed to thing.

Comment: It's not legal, but you could add specializations for pointer types that don't define the class, just declare it so you'll get a compiler error.

Comment: @NathanOliver you're right, that's why I said if the OP used a custom comparator, he should be aware of that.

Comment: @NathanOliver Having a pointer as a key is perfectly fine for insertion and lookup, as long as you don't iterate on the container. I'm trying to find existing instances of this in a large codebase.

Comment: Here is an example on how to screw with set of pointer : https://onlinegdb.com/SJqNltXMB (don't try this at home...)

Comment: @Trillian If you are just comparing address, do you keep track of deleted object so you remove them from the container ? The program can store a new object in a memory address that was used before. And I'm not sure to understand what you mean by "find existing instances of this" .

Comment: You said you used range based loop. Why are you using such range since you know that address are not used in a deterministic way ? And what kind of 'black magic' do you intend to use with static_assert ?

Comment: @Nico238 There's no trick to the question. No objects are getting deleted whose pointers are in the map. I'm not voluntarily adding those loops, I'm trying to find them in a large codebase and avoid more of them being introduced in the future. It's so easy for any of our several devs to write `for (auto pair : map)` without thinking about it, and easy for those to escape code review too. The "black magic" would just be whatever template specialization tricks needed to get an error when this pattern is used.

Comment: @Trillian I can only suggest encapsulation : store your maps in a class that hide them and only give user access to the "legal" operations. But I realize that this option may not be one you can choose because it will require a lot of code rework.

Comment: Note that there are static analyzers to detect nondeterministic iteration e.g. [CSA](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/analyzer/checkers.html#alpha-nondeterminism-pointeriteration-c) and [FlakyIterators](https://github.com/yugr/FlakyIterators).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can almost achieve the desired behavior with partial specializations:

> 20.5.4.2.1  The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it adds declarations or definitions to namespace std or to a namespace within namespace std unless otherwise specified. A program may add a template specialization for any standard library template to namespace std only if the declaration depends on a user-defined type and the specialization meets the standard library requirements for the original template and is not explicitly prohibited.

Therefore, a simple specialization for std::map can be used to detect attempts to instantiate the template with a pointer key type:

```
#include <map>

namespace internal
{
  // User-defined type trait
  template<class Key, class T>
  class DefaultAllocator
  {
  public:
    using type = std::allocator<std::pair<const Key, T>>;
  };

  // Effectively the same as std::allocator, but a different type
  template<class T>
  class Allocator2 : public std::allocator<T> {};
}

namespace std
{
  // Specialization for std::map with a pointer key type and the default allocator.
  // The class inherits most of the implementation from
  // std::map<Key*, T, Compare, ::internal::Allocator2<std::pair<Key*, T>>>
  // to mimic the standard implementation.
  template<class Key, class T, class Compare>
  class map<Key*, T, Compare, typename ::internal::DefaultAllocator<Key*, T>::type> :
    public map<Key*, T, Compare, ::internal::Allocator2<std::pair<Key*, T>>>
  {
    using base = map<Key*, T, Compare, ::internal::Allocator2<std::pair<Key*, T>>>;
    using base::iterator;
    using base::const_iterator;

  public:
    // Overload begin() and cbegin()
    iterator begin() noexcept
    {
      static_assert(false, "OH NOES, A POINTER");
    }
    const_iterator begin() const noexcept
    {
      static_assert(false, "OH NOES, A POINTER");
    }
    const_iterator cbegin() const noexcept
    {
      static_assert(false, "OH NOES, A POINTER");
    }
  };
}

int main()
{
  std::map<int, int> m1;
  std::map<int*, int> m2;

  // OK, not a specialization
  m1[0] = 42;
  for (auto& keyval : m1)
  {
    (void)keyval;
  }

  m2[nullptr] = 42;       // Insertion is OK
  for (auto& keyval : m2) // static_assert failure
  {
    (void)keyval;
  }
}
```

However,

- I haven't figured out a way to extend this for custom allocators: the declaration of the specialization has to depend on some user-defined type.
- This is a terrible kludge, so I would only use it to find existing cases (rather than keeping as a static checker).

Comment: That's the kind of thing I was hoping to see haha! Good trick on using a different template parameter to reuse the base class. I wouldn't keep this permanently but it'll probably work as a one-time check for the cases I'm interested in. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One approach to achieve a compile time failure for designated pointer types is to delete std::less, std::greater, std::hash, etc specializations for the specific pointer types that are susceptible to non-deterministic behavior (i.e. returned by interfaces).  There are many options to provide "safe" functionality for pointer collections.

The following is a comprehensive example:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <memory>
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <unordered_map>

#define DISABLE_NUMERIC_POINTER_SPECIALIZATIONS(T) \
namespace std { \
    template <> struct hash<const T*> { std::size_t operator()(const T* obj) const = delete; }; \
    template <> struct hash<T*> { std::size_t operator()(T* obj) const = delete; }; \
    template <> struct less<const T*> { bool operator()(const T* lhs, const T* rhs) const = delete; }; \
    template <> struct less<T*> { bool operator()(T* lhs, T* rhs) const = delete; }; \
    template <> struct greater<const T*> { bool operator()(const T* lhs, const T* rhs) const = delete; }; \
    template <> struct greater<T*> { bool operator()(T* lhs, T* rhs) const = delete; }; \
    template <> struct less_equal<const T*> { bool operator()(const T* lhs, const T* rhs) const = delete; }; \
    template <> struct less_equal<T*> { bool operator()(T* lhs, T* rhs) const = delete; }; \
    template <> struct greater_equal<const T*> { bool operator()(const T* lhs, const T* rhs) const = delete; }; \
    template <> struct greater_equal<T*> { bool operator()(T* lhs, T* rhs) const = delete; }; \
}
namespace NS {
class C {
public:
    explicit C(int id) : m_id{id} {}
    int id() const { return m_id; }
private:
    int m_id;
};
inline bool operator ==(const C& lhs, const C& rhs) { return lhs.id() == rhs.id(); }
inline bool operator <(const C& lhs, const C& rhs) { return lhs.id() < rhs.id(); }
}   // namespace NS
namespace std {
    template <> struct hash<NS::C> { std::size_t operator()(const NS::C& obj) const { return obj.id(); } };
}
DISABLE_NUMERIC_POINTER_SPECIALIZATIONS(NS::C)

struct IndirectEqual {
    template <typename T>
    bool operator()(const T* lhs, const T* rhs) const {
        return (lhs && rhs) ? *lhs == *rhs : lhs == rhs;
    }
};
struct IndirectLess {
    template <typename T>
    bool operator()(const T* lhs, const T* rhs) const {
        return (lhs && rhs) ? *lhs < *rhs : lhs < rhs;
    }
};
struct IndirectGreater {
    template <typename T>
    bool operator()(const T* lhs, const T* rhs) const {
        return (lhs && rhs) ? *lhs > *rhs : lhs > rhs;
    }
};
struct IndirectHash {
    template <typename T>
    std::size_t operator()(const T* ptr) const {
        return ptr ? std::hash<T>{}(*ptr) : std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max();
    }
};

struct BuiltinLess {
    template <typename T>
    bool operator()(const T& lhs, const T& rhs) const { return lhs < rhs; }
};
struct SPLess {
    template <typename T>
    bool operator()(const std::shared_ptr<T>& lhs, const std::shared_ptr<T>& rhs) const { return lhs.get() < rhs.get(); }
};
struct BuiltinGreater {
    template <typename T>
    bool operator()(const T& lhs, const T& rhs) const { return lhs < rhs; };
};
struct PtrHash {
    template <typename T>
    std::size_t operator()(const T* ptr) const { return static_cast<std::size_t>(ptr); };
};

template <typename T>
class BasicSet : private std::set<T, BuiltinLess> {
public:
    using std::set<T, BuiltinLess>::set;
    using std::set<T, BuiltinLess>::find;
    using std::set<T, BuiltinLess>::insert;
    using std::set<T, BuiltinLess>::emplace;
    using std::set<T, BuiltinLess>::end;
};
template <typename T>
class BasicSet<std::shared_ptr<T>> : private std::set<std::shared_ptr<T>, SPLess> {
public:
    using std::set<std::shared_ptr<T>, SPLess>::set;
    using std::set<std::shared_ptr<T>, SPLess>::find;
    using std::set<std::shared_ptr<T>, SPLess>::insert;
    using std::set<std::shared_ptr<T>, SPLess>::emplace;
    using std::set<std::shared_ptr<T>, SPLess>::end;
};

int main()
{
    // All of these decls result in a compiler error
    // std::set<NS::C*> unsafe_s{new NS::C{1}, new NS::C{2}}; 
    // std::map<NS::C*, int> unsafe_m{ {new NS::C{1}, 100} };
    // std::unordered_set<NS::C*> unsafe_us{new NS::C{1}, new NS::C{2}}; 
    // std::unordered_map<NS::C*, int> unsafe_um{ {new NS::C{1}, 123} };

    std::set<NS::C*, IndirectLess> s{ new NS::C{1} };
    std::unordered_set<NS::C*, IndirectHash> us1{ new NS::C{1} };
    std::unordered_set<NS::C*, IndirectHash, IndirectEqual> us2{ new NS::C{1} };

    auto c = new NS::C{1};
    assert (s.find(c) != s.end());
    assert (us1.find(c) == us1.end());  // pointers aren't equal
    assert (us2.find(c) != us2.end());  // objects are equal

    BasicSet<NS::C*> bs{ new NS::C{1} };
    assert (bs.find(c) == bs.end());    // pointers aren't equal 
    auto sp1 = std::make_shared<NS::C>(10);
    auto sp2 = std::make_shared<NS::C>(20);
    BasicSet<std::shared_ptr<NS::C>> spset{sp1, sp2};
    assert(spset.find(sp1) != spset.end());

    return 0;
}
```

Note: This isn't perfect.  E.G., one would need to disable 'volatile T*' and 'const volatile T*' variations.  I'm sure there are other issues.